# Is there command to stop execution of the jsp file?

Tags: java, jsp

I have a JSP file that contains lots of if statements.

Is there a way to stop execution of file on demand?

For example:

Can I change:

```
if (x==y) {
...
} else {
...
}
```

to:

```
if (x==y) {
....
stopExecution();
}
....
```

Comment: What do you expect the result to be if you "stop execution"? Just send the page until the current place? Try `return;`.

Comment: I want to save me the else {}. i want it just to return.. so i'll try return; :) didn't know i can do that in jsp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you already found out, you can `return;` to "stop" execution.
This works because Java code is generated from the JSP with

```
public void _jspService(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws java.io.IOException, ServletException {
    // ...
}
```

method being the entry point. If you write a `return` in that code, the method will return. You can check out the generated code in tomcat under `$TOMCAT/work/Catalina`.

Comment: This gave me a JasperException for unreachable code after the return.

Comment: Was that an unconditional `return`? That would generally give that exception.

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty basic Java I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You could use labels within Java, like:

```
 out: { 
       if( x == y) break out;
........................
       }
```

So you can put a lot of if's in the label and then break out of the whole code inside the brackets.